# store multiple values for one key in dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of data, which has 2 values:

```
a    12
a    11
a    5
a    12
a    11
```

I would like to use a dictionary, so I can end up with a list of values for each of the key. Column 1 may have a different entry, like `'b'`, so I can arrange data based on column 1 as key, while column 2 is the data for each key

```
[a:12,11,5]
```

How do I achieve this? From what I read, if 2 values has the same key, the last one override the previous one, so only one key is in the dictionary.

```
d={}
for line in results:
    templist=line.split(' ')
    thekey=templist[0]  
    thevalue=templist[1]

    if thevalue in d:
        d[thekey].append(thevalue)
    else:
        d[thekey]=[thevalue]
```

Am I approaching the problem using the wrong way?

Comment: the phrase `if thevalue in d:` actually searches the dictionary keys.  I think you want to use `if thekey in d:`

Comment: well, I am searching by value, not by key; the key may be the same, but often it is the same, so I just check that the value is not present in the list for that key

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python dicts can have only one value for a key, so you cannot assign multiple values in the fashion you are trying to.

Instead, store the mutiple values in a list corresponding to the key *so that the list becomes the one value corresponding to the key*:

```
d = {}
d["a"] = []
d["a"].append(1)
d["a"].append(2)

>>> print d
{'a': [1, 2]}
```

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to simplify this, which will initialise the key if it doesn't exist with an empty list as below:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
d["a"].append(1)
d["a"].append(2)

>>> print d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2]})
```

If you don't want repeat values for a key, you can use a set instead of list. But do note that a `set` is unordered.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)
d["a"].add(1)
d["a"].add(2)
d["a"].add(1)

>>> print d
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'a': set([1, 2])})
```

If you need to maintain order, either use sorted at runtime, or use a list
with an if clause to check for values

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for item in (1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2):
    if item not in d["a"]:
        d["a"].append(item)

>>> print d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be straightforward . One question: I need to run a check to be sure that I do not save in the dictionary a value that I already have, for that key. Do I still run [if thevalue in d:] ?

Comment: @newbiez: In that case, rather than storing the values in a `list` you can store them in a `set`, which will automatically make sure that there's only one copy of a value for any given key. However, a `set` is unordered, so it can't be indexed.

Comment: I see; I do not need to order neither the values nor the keys, I just need to be sure that I save all the values for each specific key, and that I won't have duplicates in the list; since I will parse that list later for further actions in my process.