# Parse a dictionary that contains set

Tags: python

Follow up of one of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28390941/4014959).

I have a defaultdict that uses set:

```
defaultdict(set, {'a': {'1', '3', '5', '7'}, 'b': {'8', '3', '4', '7'}})
```

Now I would like to access the data, but I cannot use the key by name, since I do not know what will be in the key.

I am able to retrieve the key, using

```
d.key[n]
```

Since I do not know the key itself but I know that there will always be 3 keys in my dictionary (-1>n<3)

Now, how do I access each value in each set? I tried with

```
d.value[0]
```

But this will return me the whole set, not just the first value in the set. I also tried

```
d.key[n].value[0]
```

But I get an error because a string does not have attribute 'value'

How do you actually access data with set as value in a dictionary?

This is my code:

```
d=defaultdict(set)
for line in results:
    templist=line.split(' ')
    thekey=templist[0]  
    thevalue=templist[1]

    d[thekey].add(thevalue)

print d.keys()[0]
print d.values()[0]
```

This will return my key, but the second print will not return the first value of the set, but the whole set.

Comment: `just the first value in the set` - There is no *first value* in a set, because sets are not ordered.

Comment: Your example code doesn't show a defaultdict or a set.  Please show actual code.

Comment: I need all of them, but one at time. I thought that a set has a concept of how many entry are in the list, so you can access them

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current example, you will need to store the key and access values using it:

```
key = d.keys()[0]
print d[key][0]
```

---

Assuming your dict looks like

```
d = {'a':[1,3,5,7], 'b':[4,7,3,8]} #or
d = {'a':{1,3,5,7}, 'b':{4,7,3,8}}
```

You can iterate over all the keys and its values using

```
for key, value in d.items():
     for item in value:
         print key, item
```

This will give the output

```
a 1
a 3
a 5
a 7
b 4
b 7
b 3
b 8
```

Comment: Yes, this will print the list, although I am trying to get just one value at time, like 1,3, 5,7 and so on

Comment: @newbiez The middle code does exactly that. I do `print key, item`, you can do `print item ` within that for loop if you want the value alone.

Comment: True, sorry; is getting late and my head is starting to stall. The solution where I store the key first and then iterate is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A set is unordered, a list is ordered. In a set there are no `first` or `last` elements, just elements. Say you have marbles in a bag, now, which one of them is first and which is last? There is no order. But you can take them *out* 1 at a time and that has an order. Put them back to bag and you get another order.

You can take the elements out of the set with `list()`, as if they were marbles in bag:

```
>>> x = set(['banana', 'apple', 'orange'])
>>> list(x)
['apple', 'orange', 'banana']  # or possibly some other ordering
```

or you can iterate over them in a for loop

```
>>> for fruit in x:
...     print(fruit)
```

But every single run time you could possibly get a different order of elements, usually though Python will give the same ordering for the same *object* if no changes happen.

Thus to your original problem. You do not access a dictionary by `values()`. In a dictionary there is no order of values either, it is again like a bag of marbles. Instead you access them by indexing by key:

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'a': {1, 3, 5, 7}, 'b': {8, 3, 4, 7}})
>>> d['a']
{1, 3, 5, 7}
>>> as_list = list(d['a'])
>>> print(as_list[0])
1
```

But this is not what a set is usually used for, the "first" value could be anything, even though now it just *happens* to be the smallest number.

---

To print `name, value` pairs you can do:

```
>>> for key, value_set in d.items():
...     for value in value_set:
...         print("Key %s has value %s" % (key, value))
... 
Key a has value 1
Key a has value 3
Key a has value 5
Key a has value 7
Key b has value 8
Key b has value 3
Key b has value 4
Key b has value 7
```

Comment: Hmm can you explain more about `every single time you could possibly get a different order of elements.`? I thought the order within the elements of set remains the same once it is constructed...

Comment: Thanks, my case does not mind about the order of the elements...if I take orange or banana first, it is the same to me, since I have to parse trough all of them. Also isn't the set object retaining the order, once created? I don't see changes in the order in my code, unless the order of the set at creation time is different.